# Unique values in two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns and I need them both to be unique between each other (like it is 1 column).

My first attempt was to create sequence and set default constraints.

```
create sequence seq1
    as bigint
    start with 1
    increment by 1
    cache;
go

create table product (
    pk uniqueidentifier
    , id_1 bigint not null default (next value for seq1)
    , id_2 bigint not null default (next value for seq1)
);
go

insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
go
```

And it doesn't work. The result of query above will be:

```
id_1  id_2
 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
 4     4
 5     5
```

Currently I stopped using 2 sequences with even and not even numbers.

```
create sequence seq2
    as bigint
    start with 1
    increment by 2
    cache;
go

create sequence seq3
    as bigint
    start with 2
    increment by 2
    cache;
go
```

But if in future I will need to add another column which also must be unique I will have a problem.

I also thinked about stored procedures. Something like this works for me.

```
create procedure sp_insertProduct
as
begin
    declare @id1 as bigint = next value for seq1;
    declare @id2 as bigint = next value for seq1;
    insert into product (pk, id_1, id_2) values (newid(), @id1, @id2);
end
go

exec sp_insertProduct;
exec sp_insertProduct;
exec sp_insertProduct;
go
```

But due to my ORM framework restictions I cannot use stored procedures for inserting.

So is there a better solution for that problem?

PS. for some reasons I can not use uniqueidentifiers.

**UPDATE**
I think I need to explain question a bit clearly. I have a working solution for now (and both current answers will also work), but I wonder if there is a *extensible* solution to:

1. provide uniqueness of values in multiple columns (with ability to
   add additional columns in future).
2. avoid using uniqueidentifiers

for better understanding of question, this is how I check uniqueness:

```
with src as (
    select id_1 as id from product
    union all
    select id_2 as id from product
)
select id, count(*) as equal_values
from src
group by id
having (count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: can you put a trigger on the table?

Comment: also is this a web app, or something distributed that will run on multiple clients simultaneously?

Comment: Side note - you should avoid using the sp_ prefix, or even better no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: If each value for id1 is unique and the desired value of id2 is just id1 + 1 what is the point of the second column??

Comment: @SeanLange, no, this is not correct. I updated my question, please check it. And thnx for the link, btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
create sequence seq1
    as bigint
    start with 1
    increment by 2
    cache;
go

create table product (
    pk uniqueidentifier
    , id_1 bigint not null default (next value for seq1)
    , id_2 bigint not null default (next value for seq1 + 1)
);
go
```

doing this..

```
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
insert into product (pk) values (newid());
```

this would generate..

```
pk                                      id_1  id_2
2A159914-8105-4DC1-9D7E-570CC5444172    1     2
6DAFEF16-2B81-4A10-99EF-B3F1A74389C6    3     4
8C6F6697-D993-4320-92BB-04CD56804C5A    5     6
AC97F37F-CAC3-4E83-BDD4-4B55D009C334    7     8
3DDAADA0-D7DB-4350-8087-ABF02B539552    9     10
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa7ef/2)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10197958)

Comment: @JBKing  umm.. based on my understanding of the authors requirement.. `I have two columns and I need them both to be unique between each other (like it is 1 column).`  this provides that functionality

Comment: Your answer appears to be a copy and paste of part of the first attempt. You do see how that could be taken as a bad thing, right? If you have something additional to add about why the other part of that attempt should be scrapped state why that is messing things up here.

Comment: it may appear that way to you, but it is not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95085/discussion-between-jamied77-and-jb-king).

Comment: Imo, this solution better, than my one, because there is only one sequence, but while it solves my problem, it doesn't provide answer to main question. I have updated my question, pls check it.

Answer (score 0):

May be this seems very naive but it should work. I didn't check but you may need to add some parenthesis:

```
create table product (
    pk uniqueidentifier
    , id_1 bigint not null default (next value for seq1)
    , id_2 bigint not null default (-next value for seq1)
);
go
```